# Are the tenses of the verbs well chosen

Tags: sequence-of-tenses

I ve been watching this film for 30 minutes and I (have) already cried so I was happy when I received your message for my birthday.

Do the tenses fit here? I think so

Comment: It seems to be a non-sequitur.  Why does crying at a film make you particularly hap to receive a birthday message.

Comment: because the film was very sad  I forgot it sorry

Comment: It's not the *tenses* that are "suspect" here - it's use of the word ***when*** in that ***so-*** clause. On a superficial reading ***so I was happy*** could be seen as referring *back* to what's already been said (gives the impression you might have been weeping "tears of joy" watching the film). That's why @James initially misinterpreted it.